# Unable to Embed TinyMCE 6 Text Editor into VisualForce Page

Tags: visualforce, third-party, inputrichtext

I'm facing an issue while trying to embed TinyMCE 6 text editor into a VisualForce page. I have attempted the solution mentioned [here](https://www.gaurishgoel.com/2017/03/rich-text-editor-tinymce.html), which suggests uploading only the `tinymce.min.js` JavaScript file as a static resource. However, this approach doesn't work as it generates an error indicating that it cannot locate files included in other folders that are part of the [tinymce.zip,](https://www.tiny.cloud/get-tiny/self-hosted/) such as `themes.js`.

I also tried uploading the entire tinymce.zip file as a static resource, but I encounter the following error upon loading: **tinymce is not defined at window.onload**.

Here is the code for the VF Page:

```
<apex:page>
<head>
    <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.tinymce}/js/tinymce/TinyMCE.min.js"/>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea id="textAreaId"></textarea>
</body>

<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        tinymce.init({
            selector : "#textAreaId",
            });
        };
</script>
</apex:page>
```

I tried including the script with:

```
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.TinyMCE,'js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js')}"/>
```

also without luck.

How to upload it correctly?
I cannot use the CDN as it is an app exchange app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had an incorrect path, was missing the base folder. Here is the correct way to import it:

```
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.TinyMCE,'tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js')}"/>
```